# next(reader) deleting the first row of data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm writing a python script that reads a csv file and iterates through for any cells with an inequality and adds a new column and splits the inequality to the new cell. I want to ignore the first row of the csv as its the header but usinig next(reader) also removes the first row of data.

```
    reader = csv.DictReader(inFile)
    first_row = next(reader)
    fieldnames = list(reader.fieldnames)
    for key, value in first_row.items():
        if any(value.startswith(char) for char in ['<', '=', '>']):
            fieldnames.append(key+'_inequality')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `csv.DictReader` without a `fieldnames` argument it consumes the first row of the csv to get the dictionary keys.  This means that the header is already gone. The result is that `next(reader)` consumes your first row of data. Getting rid of `first_row = next(reader)` will solve your problem.

Note: If you were using a `csv.DictReader` with a `fieldnames` argument or a `csv.reader` the first row would contain the headings (if they were present in the file) and it would make sense to do `first_row = next(reader)`.

Heres the relevant portion from the docs for [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> The *fieldnames* parameter is a sequence. If *fieldnames* is omitted,
> the values in the first row of file *f* will be used as the
> fieldnames. Regardless of how the fieldnames are determined, the
> dictionary preserves their original ordering.